# Compare depth and scope of math syllabus between Malaysia's STPM, Gao Kao and A level

Tags: secondary-education, curriculum

Are the math syllabi of these three exams comparable? Which syllabus' scope is wider and deeper? Which helps students to be better prepared for math in undergraduate level?

I believe that A level is deeper and has wider scope but Gao Kao of China is famous for its difficulity. Also I heard my friends from Malaysia that Math in STPM is not easy.

I cannot find any comparisons of the math syllabi in these three exams in the internet. If anyone here has some experience about math in these three exams, I am really looking forward to hear about your thoughts about the math syllabus of these three exams. Thanks. And also sorry if this question is too opinion based or off topic as I do not exactly know where should I post this type of question.